# How to call a struct array to function?

Tags: c++

I have an array of struct employee which I am trying to call in the function `readFile`.

I have tried using pointers to call but they all fail and give me the same error message.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int readFile (ifstream *inFile, struct employee array[]);

int main () {
    int size = 10;
    struct employee {
        string name;
        int id;
        float salary;
    } array[size];
    ifstream inFile;
    readFile(&inFile, array);
    return 0;
}

int readFile (ifstream *inFile, struct employee array[]) {
    inFile->open("pay.txt");
    if(inFile->fail()) {
        cout << "fail";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        cout << "success";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error message I get is this:

> .cpp:16:25: error: cannot convert 'main()::employee*' to 'employee*' for argument '2' to 'int readFile(std::ifstream*, employee*)'
>     readFile(&inFile, array);

Comment: By the way, my salary cannot be represented exactly in an IEEE754 `float` (I could negotiate a raise to the next dyadic rational?). Your best bet is to work in cents when modelling money.

Comment: You should move your struct definition outside of the main function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `struct employee` is *local* to your `main` function and the other one is *global*, so it cannot convert `'main()::employee*'` to `'employee*'` because both are different types.

Move it outside to have uniform `struct employee` throughout the program and create a *local object* of `struct employee` inside the `main` function (not a good practice to create a *global variable*).

> By the way in `C++` you don't need to append `struct` everywhere when
>   using an already defined structure. Your original post looks more like programmed in `C`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct employee {
        string name;
        int id;
        float salary;
};

int readFile (ifstream *inFile, employee array[]);

int main () {
    int size = 10;
    employee array[size];

    ifstream inFile;
    readFile(&inFile, array);
    return 0;
}

int readFile (ifstream *inFile, employee array[]) {
    inFile->open("pay.txt");
    if(inFile->fail()) {
        cout << "fail";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        cout << "success";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two classes named `employee` in your code. One is in the global namespace, which is declared (not defined) in the declaration of the function `readFile`. The other class named `employee` is defined locally in the `main` function. *These two are absolutely unrelated types.*

That's why the compiler is saying that it cannot convert `main()::employee*` to `employee*`: it's trying to convert from the `main`-local type to the global type (and of course that's not possible).

What you should do is move the definition of `struct employee` outside `main`, so that `main` creates objects of the global type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct employee {
    string name;
    int id;
    float salary;
} array[size];

int readFile (ifstream *inFile, employee array[]);

int main () {
    int size = 10;
    employee array[size];
    ifstream inFile;
    readFile(&inFile, array);
    return 0;
}

int readFile (ifstream *inFile, employee array[]) {
    inFile->open("pay.txt");
    if(inFile->fail()) {
        cout << "fail";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        cout << "success";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that in C++, it's not necessary (nor common) to write `struct employee`, just `employee` is enough (as I did in the code above). Unlike in C, there is no "tag namespace", type names use the same scoping rules as everything else.